# Spring Boot static resources 404 error while deploying war on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring REST application using Spring Boot. 
I want to consume the Spring REST APIs using angular JS client.

The stack I am using is  :
Spring Boot 1.4.2 
Spring Security 
Angular JS

The issue is : 
I am not able to get static content rendered in browser.

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.atul</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootrest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springbootrest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->

         <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Serves *only* to filter the wro.xml so it can get an absolute path for the project -->
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/wro</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/wro</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                    <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/css</cssDestinationFolder>
                    <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
                    <wroFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
                    <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                    <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/wro</contextFolder>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Project Structure :

[image]

Java Code :

**Main Class :**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ // @formatter:off

    WebConfig.class,
    JPAConfig.class,
    ServiceConfig.class,
    SecurityConfig.class

})
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(App.class);
    }

}
```

Config Classes :
**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.atul.controller" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig {

}
```

**JPAConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.atul.persistent.dao")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.atul.persistent.model")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig {

}
```

**ServiceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.atul.service"})
public class ServiceConfig {

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
                //.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

I have tried placing static resources under :

1)src\main\resources

2)webapp

The generated war contains static resources inside :

1)WEB-INF/classes as well as

2)root of web application

When running url - `http://localhost:8080/contextPath/` , I am getting exception that

`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI`[/springbootrest/]`in DispatcherServlet with name`'dispatcherServlet'

Can anybody please help me here ?

Comment: The trick is to read the documentation instead of trying random locations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am putting resources in same locations   But still it is not working. Since I am packaging as war , it should be inside src/main/webapp as per documentation.

Comment: Do u have a controller method that serves / path? Try using http://localhost:8080/contextPath/index.html and see if your static content is accessible.